# for each loop after QueryFetchArrayAll

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, parallel-foreach

I have a question: I have used the following queries to get my arrays from Database:

```
$news = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT login,id FROM `users` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9");

$imgs = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT usrpic,id FROM `users` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9");
```

Now i need `$news['login']` and `$imgs['usrpic']` in one for each loop.

For example:

```
foreach($news as $new, $imgs as $img){
    <img style="border: 1px solid #8C0E0E;"src="'.$img['usrpic'].'" width="20" height="20" border="0" />
    <img style="border: 1px solid #8C0E0E;"src="'.$new['login'].'" width="20" height="20" border="0" />
}
```

Can anyone help me how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next()` function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php 
but don't forget to make sure news and img have same size :

```
if(count($news) == count($imgs)) {
    foreach($news as $new) {
        $img = next($imgs);
        <img style="border: 1px solid #8C0E0E;"src="'.$img['usrpic'].'" width="20" height="20" border="0" />
        <img style="border: 1px solid #8C0E0E;"src="'.$new['login'].'" width="20" height="20" border="0" />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are your actual queries, you should combine them into one:

```
$users = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT id, login, usrpic FROM `users` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9");
```

Then iterate the result array and output the images:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo "<img src='{$user['usrpic']}' ... />";
    echo "<img src='{$user['login']}' ... />";
}
```

Otherwise (keeping your original queries), you should make sure `$news` and `$imgs` have the same length, and then iterate one of them:

```
$size = count($imgs);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $img = $imgs[$i];
    $new = $news[$i];
    echo "<img src='{$img['usrpic']}' ... />";
    echo "<img src='{$new['login']}' ... />";
}
```